# Перехват события

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть такой код:

```
<WrapPanel>
    <WrapPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="50"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3"/>
            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="SizeAll"/>
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Transparent"/>
            <EventSetter Event="MouseEnter" Handler="Border_MouseEnter"/>
            <EventSetter Event="MouseLeave" Handler="Border_MouseLeave"/>
            <EventSetter Event="MouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="Border_MouseLeftButtonDown"/>
            <EventSetter Event="MouseLeftButtonUp" Handler="Border_MouseLeftButtonUp"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="local:MyThumb">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="40"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"/>
        </Style>
    </WrapPanel.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle Tag="Class1;120;60"/>
        <local:MyThumb Template="{StaticResource Class1Toolbox}"/>
    </Grid>
```

Мне необходимо сделать так чтобы local:MyThumb не реагировал на MouseEnter, потому что иначе не срабатывает событие MouseLeftButtonDown у Rectangle.

Comment: А если установить `IsHitTestVisible = False`?

Answer (score 2):

помогло это:

```
IsHitTestVisible=False
```

Comment: Имейте ввиду, что это сделает ваш контрол полностью "прозрачным" для мыши. Это вам подходит?

Comment: Да, у меня в прямоугольнике элементы, а данные об этих элементах в теге у прямоугольника, поэтому мне просто требовалось их отобразить, чтобы они как бы не перекрывали мой прямоугольник.

Comment: @D.Malakhov объединили учетки вам, теперь и вопрос, и ответ — ваши.